# Send custom data (100k) to a Canvas URL

Tags: integration, json, canvas

I am planning on using Canvas to lightweight integrate an external web app. In the documentation (https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/218/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/canvas_framework.pdf) I wasn't able to find an example on how to send more heavyweight context data to the Canvas URL endpoint.

I need to seen not only user information but also the current record and a few child records (formatted as JSON) to the Canvas.

How would I do this?

Comment: How are you hosting the external web app in salesforce. Is it a standalone tab or a canvas app tag inside a lightning component or a VF page?

Comment: It's Lightning Aura components using force:canvasApp.

Comment: So inside a lightning component you are using a force canvasApp tag correct? sorry for asking i am confirming what you are trying before i put the solution that we did to pass parameters

Comment: Yes that is the plan. On the Home page there is an Aura Component which should have a Canvas tag, but I am looking for a way to pass/send more data to the Canvas. Not only the calling user but also the current record and some other child records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum size of canvas parameters seems to be 32kB. At least it is documented for the Apex `setParametersAsJSON(jsonString)` method:

> If the provided JSON string exceeds 32KB, a System.CanvasException
>   will be thrown.

(via https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_canvas_EnvironmentContext_setParametersAsJSON.htm)

Answer (score 4):

In the force canvas app there is a attribute parameters which you can use to send parameters as name value pair. documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:canvasApp/specification)

> Object representation of parameters passed to the canvas app. This
>   should be supplied in JSON format or as a JavaScript object literal.
>   Here’s an example of parameters in a JavaScript object literal:
>   {param1:'value1',param2:'value2'}. If not specified, defaults to null.

Component markup code:

```
  <force:canvasApp developerName="TestCanvas" height="850px" width="100%"
                                             parameters="{!v.canvasParams}" />
```

Javascript controller code:

```
var canvasParams = {
                            "userType": "Test",
                            "agencyId": "agencyname"
                        };
component.set("v.canvasParams", JSON.stringify(canvasParams));
```

Comment: How are those parameter send? Via insecure GET params. Then I can't use them. Can I use POST instead? And is there a size limitation? I also don't get what I need the third code example for. The Apex with the signed request.

Comment: In the connected app you create for the canvas app if you choose signed request as the access method it does a post and not a get. check page page 25, point 13 in the link you have shared in the question, I am not aware of size limitation since its not there in the documentation, the apex code i put in the question was just for illustration on how the parameters are received in the canvas app.

Comment: Check page 34 from the guide, where it says if you set access to admin pre-approved it always does a post to the canvas app URL

Comment: Sounds convincing. Can you add a bit detail to you Apex code (or remove it from the Answer) please? From which class is it? The VF controller or the custom class for the Canvas Lifecycle?

Comment: removed the apex code part from the answer